# ¿Como agregar registros masivos a una tabla desde Django Shell?

Tags: python, django

Tengo un excel con toda la información y quisiera poder hacer un query por medio de django shell para cargar todo eso a una tabla

#MODEL

```
class Area(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    PABELLONES_CHOICES = [
        ('Primaria', 'Primaria'),
        ('Secundaria', 'Secundaria'),
        ('Inicial', 'Inicial'),
        ('Coliseo', 'Coliseo'),
        ('Administrativo', 'Administrativo'),
    ]
    pabellon = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PABELLONES_CHOICES)
    ubicacion = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

Gracias por su ayuda, buscare por mi parte tambien

Exportar de excel a un tabla por medio de django shell

Comment: Tienes errado un concepto, necesitas IMPORTAR  a una tabla no exporta a una tabla. Para eso existe una librería llamada [`django-import-export`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) que te permite gestionar este tema de importar o exportar archivos ya sea mediante el shell o el admin. Revisa la documentación a ver si te funciona.

Comment: En caso contrario no conozco un comando que desde el shell te deje hacer eso (load data solo carga json y xml), lo que tendrías que hacer es crear un comando personalizado al cual le pasaras la ruta del archivo como argumento y empleando pandas te tocará leer ese archivo, procesarlo para utilizar las columnas y filas necesarias para luego insertar los datos a la tabla. Tu evalúa que opcion te puede funcionar. PD: No conozco mucho de Django así que no esta demás que algún conocedor más de este tema de su opinión.